# Fire an event when SVG Snap canvas is clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick, raphael, snap.svg

I want to keep track of when my SVG Snap canvas is clicked.

```
 var s = Snap("#svgout"), //creates the canvas
        source = "data:image;base64," + $('#imageBtn').val(), //set map background for canvas
        img = s.image(source, 0, 0, "100%", "100%"), currRect, numNodes = 0;

        s.click(function(){
            console.log("clicked canvas");
        });
```

Basically, my SVG is a background and within it I have a few elements (groups) which I am dragging and dropping. My problem is that click happens not only when the canvas is clicked,but also when I click one of my elements to drag it or just click them in gerneral. How can I fire this event only when the canvas is clicked and not when elements within my canvas are cliked?

```
           var rect = s.rect(posx, posy, 40, 40, 6).attr({
                fill: "none",
                stroke: "#F44336",
                strokeWidth: 3,
                myId: guidGenerator(),
            });

            var group = s.group(rect).attr({
                cursor: "move",
            });


            if(numNodes > 0){
                currRect.removeAttribute('stroke');
            }


            currRect = group.node.childNodes[0];

            group.append(s.image("../images/pi.svg", posx, posy, 40, 40));

            group.drag(move,start, up);
```

Comment: cant you put the svg elements outside of the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to check if it is actually the canvas being clicked is by checking the targets ID.

```
var paper = Snap("#svgout");

paper.click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.id == "svgout") {
    console.log("Canvas Clicked");
  }
});
```

Another way to stop the canvas being clicked when the children are being clicked is to execute `stopPropagation()` on the event passed to the click method of the children.

The problem with this method is that you must add it to evey child element. If I were you I'd go with the  first example.

```
var rect = paper.rect(0,0,40,40);

rect.click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note: Both methods have been tested by me using SnapSVG V0.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Few options I can think of...

Put a rect over the svg with a very small opacity, eg. 0.00001. Put the click handler on that, rather than the canvas.

Or, if you put the click handler on the canvas, check the target of the click. If its the canvas, then do something, otherwise ignore it (or do something else).

Or, maybe set a class of svgcanvas, and svgdraggables which the canvas has, or the draggable elements. Then change that class if needed do the svgdraggables have 'pointer-events: none', and then put it back on after.

Comment: Thanks, I tried option 2 but even when I click one of my drag and drop elements it registers as being the canvas...

Comment: Can you put a fiddle up ?